# in panel, datagridview size change dynamically...labels should appear after the datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, panel, autoresize

i have a datagridview in the panel and have labels just below the datagridview in design time, at run time numbers of rows changed in datagridview and its size changed accordingly.

all i want whatever is size of datagridview label appear after the datagirdview.

in my attached pic you can see labels appear top of  the datagridview

i need to create png file from panel when panel scroll who can i take pic of complete panel [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS83P.png)

this is code create png from penal but not working as require

> 'Try
> '    Using bmp = New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height)
> '        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height))
> '        bmp.Save("D:\ejaz" + TxtOrderNo.Text + ".png")
> '        'bmp.Save("D:\ejaz\image.png")
> '    End Using
> '    MessageBox.Show("Receipt saved successfully.")
> 'Catch
> '    MessageBox.Show("Error.....")
> Blockquote

please help how can i fix this problem....

[image]

Comment: Can't you just put a screenshot instead of trying to describe your confusing UI ?

Comment: thanks for advise... screen shot added..

Comment: Have you done anything with the docking and anchoring on your controls & panel(s)?

Comment: @ hutsey ,no i have anchoring every control to "bottom"... nothing with done with docking ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the row count of datagrid then push the control's location below accodtingly..

24 is one row heigth

Dim rc As Object = DgvReceipt.RowCount

```
    If rc > 4 Then

        Dim rcc As Integer = rc - 4

        GroupBox5.Location = New Point(10, 266 + rcc * 24)

        PbBarCode1.Location = New Point(17, 320 + rcc * 24)

        PbBarCode.Location = New Point(17, 381 + rcc * 24)

        Label12.Location = New Point(17, 450 + rcc * 24)

    End If
```

Comment: all control anchoring top ... vertical scroll bar working fine on form.. but when i take png from panel ... iam not getting full panel picture only the part in default size. any one help in this regard